# Trissecting by Ruler and Compass

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I am learning Galois Theory by myself and studying its glorious applications. In the section of Straightedge and compass I got stuck at the following: Let  be an angle whose cosine is equal to $1/9$. How do I show that the cosine of $\theta /3$ satisfies a polynomial equation of degree 3, and that it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Why the angle  cannot be trissected by ruler and compass?

Thanks

Comment: By Wantzel's theorem, an angle is constructible with ruler and compass only if its cosine is an algebraic number having degree a power of two. If the minimal polynomial of $\cos\theta/3$ has degree $3$, then $\theta/3$ cannot be constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triplication formula:
$$
\cos(3\alpha)=4\cos^3\alpha-3\cos\alpha
$$
(this can be derived directly from the addition formulas). If $\alpha=\theta/3$ and we set $r=\cos(\theta/3)$, then we get
$$
\frac{1}{9}=4r^3-3r
$$
that becomes
$$
36r^3-27r-1=0
$$
For simplicity, let $s=6r$, so we get
$$
\frac{1}{6}s^3-\frac{9}{2}s-1=0
$$
or
$$
s^3-27s-6=0
$$
The polynomial $X^3-27X-6$ satisfies Eisenstein's criterion for the prime $3$, hence it is irreducible over the rational numbers.

It follows that $s$ has degree $3$ over the rationals and the same is true for each of its rational multiples, including $r=\cos(\theta/3)$.

A consequence of [Wantzel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass-and-straightedge_construction) is that a necessary condition for an angle to be constructible with ruler and compass is that its cosine is an algebraic number having degree a power of $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the product to sum formula, we have

$$
\cos^2(\theta/3)=\frac{1}{2}[1+\cos(2\theta/3)].
$$

Therefore, we have
$$
\cos^3(\theta/3)=\frac{1}{2}[1+\cos(2\theta/3)]\cos(\theta/3)=\frac{1}{2}\cos(\theta/3)+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2\theta/3)\cos(\theta/3).
$$

Using the product to sum formula again, we have
$$
\cos^3(\theta/3)=\frac{1}{2}\cos(\theta/3)+\frac{1}{4}[\cos(\theta/3)+\cos(\theta)]=\frac{3}{4}\cos(\theta/3)+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{9}.
$$

Therefore, $\cos(\theta/3)$ satisfies the polynomial $x^3-3x/4-1/36=0$.